# Inserting a multipolygon with odp.net

Tags: sql, oracle, vba, odp.net

I have a string (GeoObj.ToString) defining the multipolygon:
MULTIPOLYGON (((1 1 0, 1 10 0, 10 10 0, 10 1 0, 1 1 0), (2 2 0, 2 4 0, 4 4 0, 4 2 0, 2 2 0), (5 5 0, 5 9 0, 9 9 0, 9 5 0, 5 5 0)), ((11 11 0, 11 20 0, 20 20 0, 20 11 0, 11 11 0), (12 12 0, 12 14 0, 14 14 0, 14 12 0, 12 12 0), (15 15 0, 15 19 0, 19 19 0, 19 15 0, 15 15 0)))

and a table called TEST_POLYGON with an ID (varchar2(38)) and a Geometry field (SDO_GEOMETRY).

Now I'm trying to insert the multipolygon by this way:

```
Dim oda = New OracleDataAdapter()
Dim insertStatement = "INSERT INTO TEST_POLYGON (ID, GEOMETRY) "
insertStatement = insertStatement & " VALUES (:id, sdo_geometry(:geometry)) "
oda.InsertCommand = New OracleCommand(insertStatement, dbConn)
oda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":id", Guid.NewGuid.ToString)
oda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":geometry", GeoObj.ToString)
oda.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Guid.NewGuid.ToString is just a random uuid. But now I get following error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.sql.SQLException: -2
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", line 187
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY", line 76
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved it. 3 dimensions obviously not supported in geometry data - switching to 2D and it works flawless.